# Daisy chaining dependent AJAX requests in Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am looking to daisy chain Backbone requests in which the second request is dependent on the result of the first. How do I do it the right way? jQuery `$.done()` does not seem to work for me the right way. To explain better, here is a hypothetical example:

I have a list of suppliers and each supplier has a list of parts that they supply to the company. I want to fetch all the suppliers and then fetch all parts for this list of suppliers. Here is a sample code that I am trying to use without luck.

```
var App = {};

App.Supplier = Backbone.Model.extend({ });
App.Part = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

App.Suppliers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: App.Supplier 
});

App.Parts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Part
})

var suppliers = new App.Suppliers;
var parts = new App.Parts;

var supplier_request = suppliers.fetch();

supplier_request.done(function(){
    parts.fetch_by_suppliers([supplier1, supplier2, ...]);
});
```

What happens is the second request fires immediately after the first reply has been received and **before the `App.Supplier` models are instantiated**. The result is -- the supplier list remains empty and the second request fires off with the empty list of suppliers.

Comment: Have you tried listening for the `reset` event on the `suppliers` collection? [`fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) should call that after fetching and reseting the collection.

Comment: This looks like a good idea to try out. Would this work when I have to execute a third request before waiting for two previous requests to complete?

Comment: Depends on who is doing the listening. Nested `success` callbacks might work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this daisy chaining you'll want to pass a success callback to the `fetch` method.  The `success` callback gets passed `(collection, response)` as arguments.  You can rewrite the code in your example in the following way:

```
...

suppliers.fetch({success: 
  function(collection, response){
     parts.fetch_by_suppliers(collection);
  }
});
```

The Backbone.js documentation explains it pretty well.  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch

Hope this helps ya!

Comment: This worked for me. It was a duh moment because I had read the documentation but did not try it out as I thought `$.done()` was supposed to do the same thing as `success`. Turns out, `$.done()` fires off immediately after the AJAX response is received (jQuery events are separate from Backbone.js events).